# Firmware update

Tags: operating-system

Ok so I've been waiting for the android 7.0 update for over 3 to 4 weeks now. Should of got it last week of January but because I'm on Three they have to test it which I think is stupid because my s7 is the g930f. So it should be unlocked & I shouldn't have to wait. How can I bypass this lock so I can get the firmware update thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass this lock but you shouldn't unless you want to loose warranty.  To install unofficial software not provided by Samsung you would have to root your phone and install a ROM. But as I said I wouldnt suggest that. In your case its better to wait a little longer.

Comment: But it should of been released by now. I can install foreign firmware